Web Crawling in .net 8.0 for angular website
I want to crawl angular website - https://v16.angular.io/docs I have written a code for this
 var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
 var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions { Headless = true });
 var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
 await page.GotoAsync("https://v16.angular.io/docs");

 // Wait for the page to load fully
 await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("body");

 var content = await page.ContentAsync();
 Console.WriteLine(content);

 await browser.CloseAsync();

but it throwing a error "Executable doesn't exist at C:\Users\Vinit\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium_headless_shell-1148\chrome-win\headless_shell.exe" I have installed microsoft.playwright in  my visual studio 2022 but still getting error
can you please tell me my code is right or wrong and also how to solve this error

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/33673

Have you installed playwright chromium required browsers?
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/intro
Install required browsers. This example uses net8.0, if you are using a different version of .NET you will need to adjust the command and change net8.0 to your version.

pwsh bin/Debug/net8.0/playwright.ps1 install

this is an example from the Playwright documents, after one build it will generate a .ps1 file so you can execute using terminal, after this installation you good to run the app.
